# For what purpose is the '&-' file descriptor used in fish?

Tags: linux, fish

From the fish manual:

> [The File Descripter may be] an ampersand followed by a minus sign
>   (&-). The file descriptor will be closed

From the Arch wiki:.

> Silencing standard output:
>      $ command > &-

From this I expected it to act like an alias for `/dev/null`, but quick experimentation on the command line reveals that this is not so:

```
$ echo hello >&-  
Error while writing to stdout
write_loop: Bad file descriptor
```

Also, oddly if we add a space before the & we get a a different error:

```
$ echo hello > &-
Expected a string, but instead found a '&'
```

What on earth is going on here?  I'm running fish 2.2.0

Comment: The documentation that you quoted says it is *closed*.  Writing to a closed file descriptor generates an error, which is reported (on the standard error of course - a different file descriptor).